# redirect ex-ample.com/asdf to example.com/asdf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests from ex-ample.com to example.com. The url structure should remain the same, I only want to "replace" the "-" in domain...

```
http://www.ex-ample.com/asdf123
redirects to:
http://www.example.com/asdf123
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s just a single hyphen:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```